# NullPointer Exception When getting font files from assests using class loader

Tags: android, classloader, assets

I have this code  to get the font files from assests folder:

```
public static Typeface getMyFont(Context context, String resource) {
    InputStream is;
    Typeface font = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    AssetManager assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();

    try {
        is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        is = assetManager.open(resource);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("wwwww", line);
        }
        br.close();
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return font;
}
```

here resource is font/MYFONT.ttf in assests folder which is linked (shortcut), but i get nullpointer exception in this line:

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), line);
```

Comment: What are you even trying to do? You don't need the whole Stream and BufferedReader thing if you just want to use a custom font

Comment: second parameter in createFromAssets is the font name in assets folder

Comment: When you say 'in assets folder which is linked (shortcut)' what do you mean exactly? Are you sure that the MYFONT.ttf is actually being included in the .apk file?

Answer (score 1):

```
    my_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/MYFONT.ttf");
```

Comment: if we had copied the files this will work but of the files are linked then it will not work

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem too,  you can try surrounding the part where you add the font with try & catch block to catch a null pointer exception, so, in my case,

```
Typeface comingsoon = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "ComingSoon.ttf");
```

becomes

```
try{
    Typeface comingsoon = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "ComingSoon.ttf");
}
catch(NullPointerExecption e){
     //...
}
```